# Titanium iOS: Display gragh based on sqlite db datas

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

In Titanium, i need some guidance in plotting graph based on the sqlite db values. I tried ***Rgraph*** to plot graph, but while importing am getting errors in .css and .html files of Rgraph framework.

What i need to do to display graph based on the datas from db?

Can anyone help me in this??
Thanks in Advance!